# Real and complex line integrals:

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, contour-integration

From complex analysis I know that we define the complex line integral as follows: $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt \tag 1$$ Assuming that $\gamma$ is continuously differentiable with endpoints $a$ and $b$. Back then I did not give this too much thought, as it seems like we are simply substituting $\gamma(t)$ for $z$.

Now we are defining the line integral over a real valued scalar field $\Omega$ as follows:$$\int_C \Omega(r) = \int_a^b\Omega(r(s))ds$$ Assuming that $r(s) = (x(s), y(s), z(s))$ is a curve parametrized by arc length. To generalise this definition for curves not parametrized by arc length we use the formula for the arc length $s$:$$s = \int \lvert r'(t)\rvert dt \implies \frac{ds}{dt}=\lvert r'(t)\rvert$$ $$\therefore \quad \int_C \Omega(r) = \int_a^b\Omega(r(s))ds \stackrel{?}{=} \int_a^b\Omega(r(t))\frac{ds}{dt}dt = \int_a^b\Omega(r(t))\lvert r'(t)\rvert dt \tag 2$$

My two questions are:

- Apart from the modulus, $(1)$ and $(2)$ look very similar. Is there any intuitive connection between the the complex and real line integral? Or is it just a coincidence. After all, the multiplication $\cdot$ in $(1)$ is the complex multiplication, so these definitions may be not as similar as I think.
- What exactly is happening at the penultimate step in $(2)$? My chain of equal signs seems very handwavy, so I am assuming there is some rigour missing in my explanation.

Comment: Note to self: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124822/proving-the-link-between-complex-line-integral-and-the-line-integral-of-a-vector?rq=1) may help to answer the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$, where $f\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and $\int_\gamma \Omega(\vec r)\,|d\vec r|$, where $\Omega(\vec r)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec r\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are quite different.

In the complex plane, the arc length $s$ of the curve $\gamma$ parameterized by $z(t)$, $t\in [a,b]$ is witten

$$s=\int_\gamma |dz|=\int_a^b \left|\frac{dz}{dt}\right|\,dt$$

Therefore, one should compare the real part or imaginary part of $\int_\gamma f(z)\,|dz|$ with $\int_\gamma \Omega(\vec r(t))\,|\vec r'(t)|\,dt$.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have started to realise that real and complex line integrals are really quite different for obvious reasons. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Relation_of_complex_line_integral_and_line_integral_of_vector_field) comparison between complex line integrals and line integrals of vector fields was also helpful, and I probably need to read a bit more on the subject before I understand it fully. Do you have any ideas regarding my second question?

Comment: Sure.  If $\vec r(t)$, $t\in[a,b]$ is a parameterization of the curve $\gamma$, then we can write the arclength as a function of $t$ as $s(t)=\int_a^t |\vec r'(\tau)|\,d\tau$.  Note that $s(a)=0$ and $s(b)$ gives the length of the curve $\gamma$.  Thus, using substitution we see that $s(b)=\int_{s(a)}^{s(b)}ds=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{ds(t)}{dt}\,dt=\int_a^b |\vec r'(t)|\,dt$.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thankyou. I have upvoted your answer and I will accept it in the coming days. Happy holidays to you as well!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.